# Multiple wireless magnetic reed switches

Tags: switches

I am trying to use my Pi to monitor a flat (temperature, humidity, door bell, windows and doors, camera, ...). What matters most to me at the beginning is to check whether doors or windows are opened or closed, or rather when they last got opened or closed. For the same reasons, I want the devices to be small and discreet. Wired switches are not an option for me.

I need help to find a small, battery-powered reed switch which is able to send an encoded signal, via radio, once a window or door is opened (something like http://tinyurl.com/q2cgdee). On the other side, a receiver would be connected to the Pi, which receives the encoded signal, which can be traced back to specific reed switch/transmitter.

Comment: It looks a lot like this project addresses all of your requirements: http://projects.privateeyepi.com/ .

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try RaZberry, wireless daughter card on the 885MHz.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Note: you have not even included a link to the product, second if you are in anyway affiliated with this product you should make that clear.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.